# how to update material ui textfield correctly onChange and put value into Json object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to update the title and body objects within my array with the value provided from the input fields that mapped to the array length. The body object updates perfectly but the title updates with only the current input value. For instance, if I were to try and type "the".

> The title object would change as follows "title: "t"" => "title: "h""
> => "title: "e".
>
> Desired output would be "title: "t"" => "title: "th"" => "title:
> "the".

This works with the body so I am confused why it is not with the title maybe I have missed something.

```
export const NewsArticlesPage = () => {
  const [newsArticlesJson, setNewsArticlesJson] = useContext(
    NewsArticlesContext
  )

  const [numberOfSteps, setNumberOfSteps] = useState(0)

  const stepsMap = Array.apply(
    null,
    Array(numberOfSteps).fill({ title: '', body: '' })
  )

  let stepsArray = { ...stepsMap } as StepsMapProps

  const updateTileArray = (index: number, titleEventData: string) => {
    const stepsArrayData = { ...stepsArray }
    stepsArray = {
      ...stepsArrayData,
      [index]: { ...stepsArrayData[index], title: titleEventData },
    }
    console.log(stepsArray[index])
    console.log(stepsArray[index]?.title)
  }

  const updateRichTextArray = (index: number, richTextEventData: string) => {
    const stepsArrayData = { ...stepsArray }
    stepsArray = {
      ...stepsArrayData,
      [index]: { ...stepsArrayData[index], body: richTextEventData },
    }
    console.log(stepsArray[index])
    console.log(stepsArray[index]?.body)
  }

  return (
    <NewsArticlesWrapper>
      <TextField
        type="number"
        label="Number of steps"
        value={numberOfSteps}
        InputProps={{ inputProps: { min: 0 } }}
        onChange={(e) => setNumberOfSteps(Number(e.target.value))}
      />
      {stepsMap.map((n, index) => (
        <>
          <Typography key={'heading' + index}>Step: {index + 1}</Typography>
          <TextField
            key={'title' + index}
            type="text"
            label="Title"
            value={stepsArray[index]?.title}
            onChange={(titleEventData) =>
              updateTileArray(index, titleEventData.target.value)
            }
          />
          <ReactQuill
            key={'quill' + index}
            theme="snow"
            value={stepsArray[index]?.body}
            modules={modules}
            onChange={(richTextEventData) =>
              updateRichTextArray(index, richTextEventData)
            }
          />
        </>
      ))}
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        colour="primary"
        size="medium"
        onClick={updateNewsArticleJson}
      >
        Submit Article
      </Button>
    </NewsArticlesWrapper>
  )
}
```

If any extra information is needed to help me please ask.

Code Sandbox set up to replicate issue: https://codesandbox.io/embed/kind-buck-shg2t?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Setting `Array(numberOfSteps).fill({ title: '', body: '' })` to `Array(numberOfSteps).fill({ title: null, body: 'null})` fixed the issue but I don't understan why?

Comment: What is `stepsMap` even doing? It return an empty array when I run? And why is `stepsArray` an object, when the name says 'Array'?

Comment: stepMap allows me to map the number of input fields needed based on the input number of steps, the second part of your question is simply poor/incorrect naming convention on my part.

Comment: I hope that makes sense?

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Can you provide a minimal sandbox for this code?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/kind-buck-shg2t?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Here is a code sandbox I built works exactly like my code has the same error

Answer (score 0):

`<TextField />` and `<ReactQuill />` input components are defined in a ‘controlled component’ way. The object they’re setting / getting values to is `stepsArray` which you have created as a normal object

```js
let stepsArray = { ...stepsMap } as StepsMapProps
```

The `onChange` handler  on both these components are changing values on this object

```js
stepsArray = {
    ...stepsArrayData,
    [index]: { ...stepsArrayData[index], title: titleEventData },
}
```

but, there isn't a re-render, because React re-renders when state changes. `stepsArray` is a normal js object, and although the value is changing, it is not causing a re-render. This is the reason, you cannot see the value you type on Title `<TextField />`component.

To solve this, make the object where you’re setting/getting values to, with `useState`, and use the `set(State)` function provided by the `useState` hook accordingly to update values inside the object. This will cause a re-render whenever input's value changes, because now you will be changing the object created through `useState`'s setter function and your UI will be in sync with the state.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-buck-shg2t?file=/src/App.js